# Submitting to app store, in "Prepare for Submission", how long do I get?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

So I just had a bit of a panic and realised that the app name I want may not be available. Just went ahead and created an app in iTunes Connect using the bundle id, sigh of relief, it is available.

I am about a week or two away from finishing. Filled out Description and uploaded one screenshot.

How long do I have to finish these details before it is deleted?

Do I need to enter any more details or click on submit for review yet?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has changed the rules a number of times, but a fairly recent (October 2014) [blog post](http://blog.salsitasoft.com/apples-new-app-name-reservation-policy/) suggests that these app name reservations no longer automatically expire. The author says he received the following e-mail from Apple:

[image: E-Mail from Apple stating app name expiration is no longer a feature of their program.]

This was posted as an [answer to a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28179794). The [accepted answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17748195) still states there is a time limit of 180 days, but the answer was last edited in March 2014, and the quote it gives no longer seems to appear on the page it links to.

Comment: I don't need to click "Submit for Review" to keep the name then right? Just wait until the app is ready to upload?

Comment: No. The review that Apple does covers the screenshots, description and so on, and importantly, the app itself. As I recall, if you haven't uploaded a binary, and you click “Submit for Review”, you’ll get a message saying that you need to upload a binary before you can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Forever. I have a project I made in November, and it's still here. (Even better: if you make some bad project, you can't delete it until you release it to the App Store!)

Comment: So I don't have to click anything? literally all I've done is type some of the description and clicked save. I don't need to click submit for review until it's done right?

Comment: @KeX Nope. You have unlimited time, unless Apple says differently for some reason.

Comment: Cool, and the app name is the one displayed at the top left of the control panel right? It's the first screen when you choose an app name, the bundle and sky that will tell you if the name is available or not, this correct?

Comment: @KeX Yes. If it isn't available, it wouldn't let you create the app.

Comment: Thanks. It seems strange you can keep the name forever. Surely if you ever think up an app name you can just create a nice empty application and use the bundle and create a new app whenever you want, sitting on the name indefinitely. As long as you use the same bundle id you are good to go.